# Azure Application Log Not Showing Trace Messages

Tags: c#, api, azure, logging, asp.net-core

I am trying to use Trace Logging in Azure with a Asp.Net Core 2 API. I have an AppService and have gone to the Diagnostics Logs section and enabled Applicationo Logging (Blob) and as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) that should be all I need to do? I have made the following endpoints to test this:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/TraceWarning")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TraceWarning()
    {
        Trace.TraceWarning("This is a TraceWarning Message");
        return Ok();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/TraceError")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TraceError()
    {
        Trace.TraceError("This is a TraceError Message");
        return Ok();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/ThrowError")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ThrowError()
    {
        throw new Exception("THROW ERROR");
        return Ok();
    }
```

The application logs show the end points getting hit, and show the stack trace for the error, that's great but I'm not getting the messages.

I've tried a lot of different stuff from different searches/guides, but just can't seem to get it to work.

My only conclusion is that I must be missing config of some kind somewhere. Such as, do I need to change my web config (the docs don't say to but I've seen that elsewhere)? What should the LogLevel be in my appsettings.json? Am I forced to fully integrate with Application Isights (and how would I do that)? Would there need to be other code beyond just writing the trace that I need to include at startup?

Thank you for any help, this kind of has me at the end of my ropes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Application diagnostics allows you to capture information produced by a web application. **ASP.NET applications can use the System.Diagnostics.Trace** class to log information to the application diagnostics log.

The documentation you provided is supporting **.net web app** to use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to log information.

If you are using a Asp.net Core 2 API, ASP.NET Core new project templates already setup some basic logging providers with this code in the Startup.Configure method:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(); 
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: This is the kind of oversight that makes you want to cry lol, ty.